# Url without www redirect to different page

Tags: azure, url, web, azure-devops, webserver

I am having a issue with the redirects of my URL using Microsoft Azure Web Service.

When I am executing `www.myurl.com` I am going to the correct page.

If I remove the `www` and execute `myurl.com` it redirects me to a incorrect page. The page that is shown, is only avaiable through a sub domain like `login.myurl.com`.

I am hosting on Microsoft Azure Server.

The root of the server basically contains the `index.html` on which the main page should redirect. However, without the `www` it redirect into a folder on root, and goes to the `index.php` inside that folder. There are more subfolders and it doesn't go into the alphabetic first one.

```
- www
-- index.html (this should be called)

-- // login folder
---- index.php (this is getting called without www)
```

Comment: I assume by Microsoft Azure Server you mean Azure App Service. Have you read this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain

Comment: @MartinFrøhlich Thanks and yes you are correct. Using Microsoft Azure App Server IIS. However, the domains are hosted somewhere else. Then we link the domain with the webspaces.